# How to define linear_constraint for Scipy's optimize.shgo?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

When I use Scipy's `optimize.shgo`, why do I receive an error that says

```
line 148, in scipy_shgo
   res = shgo(mae_func, bounds=bounds, constraints=linear_constraint, args=(data))

TypeError: 'LinearConstraint' object is not subscriptable
```

I do not have this error when I use `optimize.minimize` with the same linear constraints definition.

```
def scipy_shgo(id):
    data = get_data(id)
    lb = [0]
    ub = [np.inf]
    linear_constraint = LinearConstraint([0,0,-1,1], lb=lb, ub=ub)
    bounds = [(0, None)] * 4

    res = shgo(mae_func, bounds=bounds, constraints=linear_constraint, args(data))

    return res

result = scipy_shgo('some_id')
```

Comment: shgo doesn't support the LinearConstraint objects. You have to use dict constraints instead.

Comment: What part of the `shgo` documentation didn't you understand?  Looks to me like both accept a `sequence of dict` ('minimize' says `list of dict`, but uses a `tuple of dict` as an example).